# Runtime error handling on android

Tags: android, runtime-error

I want to make some classes that catch runtime errors on android and offers the user the option to restore the last saved instance state of the app.

I was thinking of extending the Activity and Fragment classes and implement something that saves their state. In the meantime, another class handles every start of an activity or fragment, putting them in a stack.

I want to catch every possible exception in the app, hopefully making errors less bothersome for the user.

Any advice on how I should handle this?

How would this error checking influence the performance of an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good solution and i don't know if it's useful for you, but you can caught exceptions in Application Class.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
  public void onCreate ()
  {
    // Setup handler for uncaught exceptions.
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
      @Override
      public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
      {
        handleUncaughtException (thread, e);
      }
    });
  }

  public void handleUncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    // do what ever you want.
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I need. Just to be sure...will this catch exceptions that run on worker threads?

Comment: this was a quick fix for a legacy android code to stop receiving  exceptions and it was successfull. After i implented this, there were no crash reports received. (I'll be glad if you accept my answer. thanks)

Comment: thanks. it worked! just made a list of fragments and activities by implementing activityLifeCycleCallbacks and handled them from there

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch blocks to catch runtime errors. If you use try catch efficiently with throws your app won't crash in first place hence no need to maintain stack of activities. btw maintaining stacks of previous activity in neither memory efficient nor advisable.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of maintaining the whole activity in the memory, just a reference to what activity was last open(a unique identifier for each activity), and reopen the last one before the crash. Although I'm not sure how important it would be to save the instance state of each activity. I might be able to do without

Comment: PS, I am using try-catch as efficiently as I can, but I am a programmer, my program is bound to crash at least once sooner or later

Comment: crashes happens due to unknown errors, hence there is no way to full proof your app in advance. so only way is, if it crashes, collect crash report from your developer console fix it as soon as you can and publish new update to users.

Comment: and if you don't let it crash you will never see flaws in your apps and bugs will go undetected for years. Since it doesn't crash user won't able to report if some functionality is broken, and you won't fix it, and you will loose your user base by your competitor.

Comment: I have already implemented a class that sends every error report to my backend, so I can fix my errors. I am simply looking for a way to make an error less displeasing to the user. Display a "I'm sorry" message and give the option to restore app.